# how to restore?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, restore

I am not sure if this has been addressed already. I have been a long time reader but this is my fifth post. I need assistance with a database restore solution. I receive a full BAK and the transaction logs 30 minutes from a supplier. I would like to restore the DB and process the TRN files nightly. The database has to be in a mode where I can query and insert the new information into a reporting database after the TRN files have been processed and then repeat the process the next night. It seems no matter what I try I get the "Different Recovery Path" error or I can process everything only for that day. I am running SQL Server 2008 R2 standard and have been banging my head on this one for about a week now.

Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you do a point in time recovery with these logs?
If not, can the supplier not send you a single bak file at the end of the day (before your restore). Then you can run a scheduled restore script with recovery changing any filename/path details to suit if necessary.
If you only restore overnight then receiving individual trn files rather than a end of day bak (that would contain the log entries that the trn files would have had) seems overkill?

Comment: Can you edit your question and paste the error. What is version and edition of SQL Server involved here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you RECOVER the database at any point between the Database restore and a transaction log, the transaction logs that follow are no longer in the same recovery path.  Recovery of the database starts a new Recovery Path.

If you are using Enterprise Edition (likely what Shanky was wondering) instead of recovering the database in order to read from it, you can create a SNAPSHOT DATABASE that you can read from.

Or, you could `RESTORE DATABASE ... WITH STANDBY = 'StandByFile'` and can also use `RESTORE LOG ... WITH STANDBY = 'StandByFile'` to allow you to read from a database still in RECOVERY.

Both of these approaches should permit you to restore further LOG backups in order to reach a new point of recovery.

There are instructions for a warm standby at: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178034(v=sql.105).aspx

From your description I am unclear on exactly when you get the backup files and what your recovery points are intended to be.  But either a SNAPSHOT database or STANDBY mode may help you.